# How to change Gsettings via remote shell?

Tags: remote-access, dconf, gsettings, puppet, remote-login

I need to automate desktop configuration via Puppet, virtual terminal  or ssh.

Unfortunately, invocation of `gsettings` via ssh or virtual terminal gives:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize "4"

(process:29520): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

When I set the `$DISPLAY` with `export DISPLAY=:0.0` it gives another error:

```
(process:29862): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

What can I do?

Comment: I was having this same issue while trying to make gsettings changes for a vagrant image via SSH during provisioning. This solution https://askubuntu.com/a/326773 did the trick for me w/o all the fishing for the active connection and trying to spoof the environment. YMMV...

Comment: On **Ubuntu 18.04** you may need to set not only `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, but also `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The key is to set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable.

On [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1059023) I found the following script, that helps to get the correct value of that variable. It requires name of the process, that is running on the desktop, on which we want to change the dbus settings. (There can be more than 1 running graphical sessions in parallel). Lets call it `discover_session_bus_address.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remember to run this script using the command "source ./filename.sh"

# Search these processes for the session variable 
# (they are run as the current user and have the DBUS session variable set)
compatiblePrograms=( nautilus kdeinit kded4 pulseaudio trackerd )

# Attempt to get a program pid
for index in ${compatiblePrograms[@]}; do
    PID=$(pidof -s ${index})
    if [[ "${PID}" != "" ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
if [[ "${PID}" == "" ]]; then
    echo "Could not detect active login session"
    return 1
fi

QUERY_ENVIRON="$(tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/${PID}/environ | grep "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" | cut -d "=" -f 2-)"
if [[ "${QUERY_ENVIRON}" != "" ]]; then
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="${QUERY_ENVIRON}"
    echo "Connected to session:"
    echo "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=${DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS}"
else
    echo "Could not find dbus session ID in user environment."
    return 1
fi

return 0
```

With this script we can do the following, assuming that `unity` process is running on the desktop, on which we want to apply our settings:

```
. ./discover_session_bus_address.sh unity
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize "4"
```

And things should work OK.

Comment: This worked right away for me!

Answer (score -1):

I have a POST-Install script that sets my gsetting. Because I run the script as sudo the EUID is 0, there fore I have to find the $RUID (Real User ID).

here is my approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Get the Real Username
RUID=$(who | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}')

# Translate Real Username to Real User ID
RUSER_UID=$(id -u ${RUID})

# Set gsettings for the Real User
sudo -u ${RUID} DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/${RUSER_UID}/bus" gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date false

exit
```

Comment: Your user ID is already stored in the `$USER` environment variable, and your UID in the `$UID` variable.  When running `sudo`, they are in the `$SUDO_USER` and `$SUDO_UID` variables. That said, why would you even run this with `sudo` in the first place? Using `sudo -u $YOUR_USER` is just like not using `sudo` at all. Finally, your `who | awk . . .` command doesn't get *your* ID, it prints *all* IDs of *all* users currently logged into the system.