# Unity/Ubuntu Desktop not showing in the Ubuntu desktop environment switcher

Tags: unity

Not sure what happened, updated Ubuntu core, rebooted, and now "Ubuntu" is gone from the desktop environment switcher on the login screen of Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to use Unity.

I have tried re-installing it and completely removing it, it won't budge.

Cinnamon and KDE are the only one's showing up

Answer (score 1):

I had lost the Unity option in the desktop environment switcher after installing Unity8 in Ubuntu 15.04. The problem included a weird situation where even "unity-desktop" did not show up in Synaptic. The solution proved pretty easy (thanks to this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479371/ubuntu-14-04-no-unity-in-user-account-but-in-guest-account)):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```