# Not able to get into console after presing Ctrl-Alt-F1

Tags: 16.04, login

I'm just a happy man, who has just installed Ubuntu 16.04. So the problem is that when I try to load, I get GRUB CLI mode.

First question I do not understand why I see grub console instead of operating system list?

Ok, if I type `exit` in this console, Ubuntu continues to load and I get to login normal login screen. And here I face two problems

1. If I try to login using this login screen, I get into the system, but I do not see Unity components at all. Ubuntu just reports some error and suggests to send a report. And nothing happens. Just empty desktop and nothing else
2. I can not get into tty's by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F3-F7 - when I press it - I just see black screen and no login request.

I strongly suspect that this mught be related to my graphics card - GTX1070. But you know, I did nothing before - just installed the system and that it - it is already not working propely.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Was Ubuntu ever running properly on that machine?

Comment: @OwenHines No. the thing is that this is first time I install it on this machine. Tried to install 14.04 before - was never able to get it working properly with my gtx 1070 and I was not able to install cuda. 16.04  has never worked properly(as well as 14.04 actually)

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/791439/trouble-installing-ubuntu-16-04-since-i-got-gtx-1070)?

Comment: @OwenHines thanks for the link - will try it. Any ideas why I see grub console, not a menu? Thanks

Comment: Probably due to Ubuntu not being able to boot properly and going into a sort of recovery mode where no user files are loaded.

Comment: Amazing that is not able to load propely right after installation even before any user interaction :) Thanks a lot for your suggestion - will be trying it out today. Thanks again!