# Ubuntu 16.04 characters invisible during boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia

[image]This is a weird problem.  My machine has an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 and, having recently reinstalled with Ubuntu 16.04-3, I now cannot see any of the characters of the boot messages.  I have encrypted file systems so need to enter the password as the machine boots.

I already knew that I needed to change the boot parameters to get the keyboard to work with the encrypted file systems so have nosplash set.  I also have nomodeset since there seems to be a known problem with the 1070 graphics card.

What I'm seeing is a blank screen but not a really blank screen (I said it was weird).  Rather than trying to describe this I have taken a photo of my monitor.

As you can see there are black lines where there should be characters.  I can type in my password and the machine boots fine, I just can't see any of the boot messages.

I'm using the NVIDIA closed source driver version 384.59.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/791439/trouble-installing-ubuntu-16-04-since-i-got-gtx-1070

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `GRUB` config and change `quiet splash` to `text`. To do this during boot, press `e` to edit, or to do it after you booted use:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

then reboot. This will boot showing you all messages instead of the splash screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.  I tried text both with and without nomodeset and got the same effect, just obviously more text that I couldn't read.  I did find the answer, which I have posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I removed the following line from my grub.cfg file:

```
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
```

And now I can see all the boot messages!