# Blue screen on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

a few days ago I ran into a [blue screen](http://nsm08.casimages.com/img/2015/02/28//1502281053207415813021253.jpg) issue after downloading some updates. Since then I've been searching for information and trying countless procedures to solve it, to no avail.

Here's some info which I hope will be useful:

- My computer: a 2008 Packard Bell PC, Intel Core 2 Quad CPU 2.4 GHz processor, 4 GB of RAM, Geforce 9300 GE graphics card.
- Kernel version: 3.13.0-46-generic
- Ubuntu version: 14.04.2 LTS

At a very high level here's what I've tried so far:

- uninstalling then reinstalling Vidia drivers,
- installing X Updates PPA,
- installing Gnome interface (which I actually can't even access)

Please advise, your help will be greatly appreciated.

**March 01st Update:**

Hello, here are today's results:

- `compizconfig-*` worked, thanks very much
- The 1st solution of thread 17381 didn't restore the GUI but displayed

  ```
  compizconfig - Info: Backend : ini
  compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
  compizconfig - Info: Profile : default
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
  ```
- the 2nd solution of thread 17381 returned (I'm just quoting what I think can help, ie the error messages):

  ```
  Glib-warning **: In call to g-spawn-sync(), exit status of a child
  process was request but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). Most likely
  the process is ignoring SIGCHLD, or some other thread is invoking
  waitpid() with a non positive first argument; either behavior can
  break applications that use g_spawn_sync either directly or
  indirectly.

  dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 
  'bus-launch --autolaunch=dfa6290d0169f2653223ea790000000000c --binary-syntax--
  close-  stderr': Child process killed by signal 43
  (...)
  Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware
  Info: Starting plugin: openg1
  ```

I didn't try creating a script as suggested in thread 457016 as I know I'll make a mess of it, especially through CLI. It seems like we're doing good progress but there's still a few hurdles on the way :)

**March 01st Update #2:**

I tried running `startx` and I could see the desktop and the files that are located there, however I have no wallpaper (but a blue background) and no taskbar and vertical iconbar. I can open the text files but not the pictures.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please post a screen shot of that?  I've never seen a blue screen in Ubuntu!  :/  Can you still go to a TTY by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][F1] and long in there?

Comment: There is no blue screen in Ubuntu... Are you using Wubi?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. Sadly there is a blue screen in Ubuntu, please see the photo I took: http://nsm08.casimages.com/img/2015/02/28//1502281053207415813021253.jpg
@Fabby I can indeed use the command line interface, this is how I performed the actions I mentioned in my first post.

Comment: Thank you! More clear now...  Please have a look at the above link and report back whether that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, however I tried all applicable suggestions but with no luck. As a noob I didn't try those involving file deletion.  
If that's any help command 'dconf reset -f /org/compiz/' returned  
    "Cannot autolaunch D-Bis without X11 display"  
Command 'apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager' returned  
    "Unable to locate package compizconfig-settings-manager".

Comment: You should try http://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell as well when you do the `dconf reset command` (I've also edited it to contain the command from the above answer) I've got 14.04.2 as well and `compizconfig-settings-manager`  *is available*, sou you should try `compizconfig-*` then.

Comment: @Fabby, thanks for your invaluable help, I edited my original post and added today's results.

Answer (score 1):

try it this way in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Then login to tty <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic

sudo reboot
```

When it's booted to make sure run:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig

gksudo nvidia-settings
```

Comment: Hello, I tried what you suggested. To run the first set of commands I had to run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`first otherwise `sudo nvidia-xconfig` would error out saying "command not found". The definition is now very low (640*480 I guess).

After rebooting I tried running the last two commands you mentioned but again I had the "command not found" error message even though I had run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` beforehand. Do you have any idea what I should do?

Comment: I ran `ccsm` and got the error message "compiz couldn't open display".
When I ran `startx`, I got the error message "error setting mtrr". Can anybody please help?

Comment: I was suggesting you bumblebee solution not nvidia-current and do this from tty terminal Ctrl+Alt+1 and stop `X` before doing so `sudo service lightdm stop` repeat the step by step.

Comment: please check my edited answer

Comment: you can also use Nvidia driver from Nvidia directly more here http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file/423619#423619

Comment: Hello, I tried to follow your suggestions as closely as I could. 

I may not have made it clear, after logging in I cannot run a terminal, all I can do is press Ctrl Alt F1. After doing so and running `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, I get an error message saying the command cannot be found.

Comment: command not found means you haven't properly installed nvidia driver or it's not activated at all. No idea why you cant run a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T you can simply `install --reinstall gnome terminal` or type terminal in Dash, otherwise also check nvidia driver to be activated go to system settings-->software&updates-->additional drivers and make sure nvidia is active. Also bumblebee should have activated it by default. Reply what you have. If you successfully installed bumblebee give the output for `prime-select query`

Comment: Hello everyone, after trying all that was suggested here (and from many more threads) I decided I'll save time by going the easy way and reinstalling Ubuntu.
Thanks for your help.