# Ubuntu Desktop isn't Working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, unity, nvidia

I deleted my previous nvidia driver and have tried to install lasted nvidia driver from nvidia.com after first login my taskbar, launcher etc.. haven't worked(cant right click on desktop, just wallpaper is shown).

I **searched** and **tried** to solve this problem with **old topics** almost I tried every suggestion on Internet but I can't fixed my issue yet.

I tried to reset tweak tool with

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

the output message is `"dconf-WARNING" **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without **X11 $DISPLAY**`. I haven't came across with that message on forums. I think my problem a bit different from others.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04LTS 64bits.
I have got GeForce GT520Mx graphic-card

I want to fix that issue without reinstalling the OS?

Comment: Have you already tried this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears ? The first and second solution works.

Comment: Yes I tryed that one. in the first solution-step 4: Find the Unity plugin. Enable it. You will be asked "Ubuntu Unity Plugin requires the plugin OpenGL. Don;t enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin / Enable OpenGL" in that step there is no possibility to disable OpenGL if Ubuntu Unity Plugin wanna be enabled. I did those steps it hasn't worked.

And at the second solution sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ that command isn't worknig for me as I mention in my post.

Comment: You have to remove the drivers, that probably are not compatible with your setup (why using untested drivers if you do not know how to recover from the damage you cause???)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Go to virtual terminal:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
Login: _
Password: _
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
```

Reboot and select gnome on login. Open terminal

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
sudo reboot
```

**Method 2:** (if Method 1 does not work)

Open virtual terminal and login:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
Login: _
Password: _
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm &
```

Press:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

*OR*

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity
sudo ccsm
```

Find Unity Plugin and enable it. Close the window.

```
sudo reboot
```

**Method 3:** (If Method 2 does not work)

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
export DISPLAY=:0   
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
reboot
```

________________________________**Now**_________________________________

Open terminal

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA
```

You will come to know your NVidia model number

Go to http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

Don't download, just give the information asked and note down the driver version suggested by them for downloading.

Let's assume it is `123.456`

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-123
reboot
```

Access NVIDIA's configuration menu using start button and searching for nvidia

Comment: That one also hasn't solved the issue for me

Comment: Try open source  Nouveau driver

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: For your error part read http://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell