# remove 'System' menu from top panel

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I have Mate desktop installed on Ubuntu and I'm trying to hide the complete 'System' menu on the top panel using commandline but couldn't figure out how to do that.

Please could anyone provide some help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s

```
$ gsettings set org.mate.panel.menubar show-desktop false
```

Comment: this works if I do it using terminal within Ubuntu . how can I achieve the same if I ssh to the machine? I got a dconf-WARNING error.failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY. where does gsettings store it file? Thanks

Comment: I found out I need to edit /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.mate.panel.menubar.gschema.xml change 'show-desktop' to false, and recompile schemas using glib-compile-schemas

Comment: It depends on whether the user session is currently running or not. So you either need to attach to the current D-Bus session or launch a new one, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell