# Lost Unity launcher and Could not find dbus session ID in user Environment

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher, dbus

I have lost my unity launcher and top panel while installing something. While recovering this issue I came across [Unity Launcher and Top Panel disappeared in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04) and  [How to change Gsettings via remote shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I tried top voted solution from above second link, but when I executed `./discover_session_bus_address.sh unity` I got following error

```
./discover_session_bus_address.sh: line 21 /proc/3608/environ:Permission denied
Counld not find dbus session ID in user environment.
./discover_session_bus_address.sh: line 28: return can only `return' from a function or sourced script
./discover_session_bus_address.sh: line 28: return can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

Please anybody can help here or some other way to fix unity launcher issue. Thanks

Comment: Exactly **how** and from **where** are you running this script?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have reinstalled as it was a bit urgent and I was not able to work.