# "gedit" does not launch as root: "CRITICAL: file log.c ..."-error (no gksu problem!)

Tags: root, gedit, dconf

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 with XFCE. Since a few weeks, `gedit` is not launching any more as root (with `gksu gedit`).

Launching with my normal account works without problems. The problem is not `gksu`, as it does the same as `sudo` (I know, not recommended for GUI) or `gksudo`. `pkexec` gives a different error. However, other programs (e.g. `eog`) run fine with `gksu`!

When I run `gksu gedit`, I get the `gksu` password prompt, and after entering it, I see the circling mouse cursor for maybe half a minute, but no `gedit` window opens. No terminal output either.

Running `pkexec gedit` in a terminal gives:

```
bytecommander@AlkaliMetal:~$ pkexec gedit
gdk_mir_display_open
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: File or Path not found.

(gedit:3935): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
bytecommander@AlkaliMetal:~$
```

Running `gedit` in a root terminal gives:

```
root@AlkaliMetal:/home/bytecommander# gedit

(gedit:24281): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" (No such file or directory)

** (gedit:24281): CRITICAL **: file log.c: line 975: unexpected error: Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" (No such file or directory) (g-exec-error-quark, 8)

^C
root@AlkaliMetal:/home/bytecommander#
```

(The command doesn't terminate. I aborted it after a while with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)

I searched for the `log.c` file from the error message. The only one I found was `/usr/share/gettext/intl/log.c`. Strange is however, that this file only contains 126 lines, so the line mentioned above (line 975) is not existing! Shall I post the content? It looks like normal C-code.

I also already deleted `/root/.config/gedit/`, but nothing changed.

Starting `dconf-editor` from a root terminal and examining the keys in `dconf:/org/gnome/gedit` did not show any suspicious (to me!) values. I can post some keys if you tell me how to dump them. I only know how to use the GUI tool.

What do I have to I do to restore my root-dconf settings for gedit (assuming this is the problem)? Or am I wrong and the problem has another cause?
Maybe you can even guess what messed it up so that I can avoid it in the future. Thanks!

Comment: The error is in line 33 of your `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file. What do you have there?

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for pointing out. I had copied a paragraph from a website into that file not noticing that it used wrong "" characters. I replaced them and now this error is gone. I updated my question. But this was not the error causing gedit to fail launching as root.

Comment: did you try just to completely reinstall gedit?

Comment: @JoKeR No. Can I backup the settings for my user profile and restore them later? (if yes: how?) Because I want to keep those settings which are working.

Comment: you can backup anything it's a bit too long to explain about backup better read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem I'd recommend you simply to `--reinstall gedit` to see if it work it might.

Comment: also a good tutorial on backing up http://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages

Comment: @JoKeR I was not asking on how to do a full backup in general, but which how I can copy only the gedit settings for one user profile to a backup location. I assume it is not a config file but dconf entries. So how could I back up (and later restore) a dconf key tree?

Comment: it's not about full system backup please read the 2nd link closer it says **personal data & settings** e.g. `rsync --progress /home/yourname/./config/.dconf` and `/path/to/user/profile/backup/here` for more options list `rsync --help`

Comment: @JoKeR I did reinstall now, but nothing changed. Still the same errors.

Comment: I might found a solution for you check this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/323776/gsettings-not-working-over-ssh

Comment: @JoKeR No, sorry. Both answers did not work. Neither the "DISPLAY=:0 gedit" nor the "dbus-launch gedit". Display changes nothing, dbus-launch tells me it is not installed, but `apt-get install dbus-x11` tells me it _IS_ installed and up to date. I bet this has to do with XFCE. Could it be that dbus is running on Unity only (and Gnome maybe)?

Comment: there are lots of bug reports even on Launchpad that similar to your issue I cannot tell exactly I use standard unity environment and I never experienced these kind of errors. Maybe try to reinstall the environment you're currently using to see if it do any change.

Comment: @JoKeR You mean `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop --reinstall`? What will happen to my settings then?

Comment: yes you can backup your settings as in my previous posts suggested though with `--reinstall` I don't think they will be removed but when you'll do `--reinstall` with `purge` before that might. But of course if it's got messed up in some way it's better off to purge it and reinstall.

Comment: I also see in one of your posts in your question it says `cannot open display` in my posted solution thread **steeldriver**'s answer provide some similar issue I think, you can try fixes with that workaround.

Comment: @JoKeR The display error was only with pkexec. But this is not the problem, neither is dbus, as it works as normal user under XFCE without dbus too. It is that "(g-exec-error-quark, 8) that is the problem.

Comment: @JoKeR I solved my problem and posted it as answer. Just if you are interested in what the problem was...

Comment: glad for you I'll give it +1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I somehow managed to solve my problem and get gedit back to work, even for root.

What I did was

1. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dbus dbus-x11`

   to reinstall some dbus-packages which I probably messed up some time ago by running `make uninstall` on a package containing dbus parts.
2. `dconf dump /org/gnome/gedit/ > /home/bytecommander/dconf-gedit.dump`
   followed by opening a root shell with `sudo -i` and as root:
   `dconf load /org/gnome/gedit/ < /home/bytecommander/dconf-gedit.dump`

   to copy the working dconf-settings for gedit from my normal user profile over to root's dconf database.

After that it works like a charm. Even the dconf-warnings about dbus-launch disappeared.

Comment: As far as I know `sudo dconf` doesn't act on the dconf database of the super-user. Instead it interacts with the current DBus session interface. You need to start a separate DBus session for the super-user and set the correct environment variables for `HOME` and `DBUS_*` for it to work.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Really? I don't know. I dumped to a file and loaded within a root shell (sudo -i). I just thought I could shorten the command. Is my real approach okay then?

Comment: I don't know. Since `sudo -i` initiates a login shell with an entirely new set of environment variables, at least it wouldn't try to use the user DBus session, but I'm not sure, if it finds or starts the correct DBus session for the super-user. You can test it, by comparing the output of `env | grep -e '^DBUS_'` in both environments. Curiously, for me it's empty after `sudo -i` and `sudo env | grep -e '^DBUS_'`. I guess, that's because `sudo` filters some well-known session-related environment variables including `DBUS_*`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I will edit it and change to my original steps then. I think it did change the values, because now I have the same colouring scheme as root like as normal user. It was different before.

Comment: `bytecommander@AlkaliMetal:~$ env | grep -e '^DBUS_' -->
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-zA0nZROAtK`
 while
`root@AlkaliMetal:~# env | grep -e '^DBUS_'` gives nothing.

Comment: @ByteCommander, Just tried your answer.. doesn't work.

Comment: @Pacerier Well, then you probably have a different problem. You should ask a new question where you describe your issue in detail. A link to this question might help if there are many similarities.